# How to get multiple selected values of select2 using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I'm trying to save multiple select2
my table looks like in this picture
[image]

the table row itself will be created by javascript on the runtime

```
function addRow_tugas_rkb(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length - 2;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var cell6 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

    cell1.innerHTML="<button type='button' onclick='delRow_tugas_rkb(this)' style='width:25px;height:25px;font-size:15px;' class='btn btn-floating btn-danger btn-sm'><i class='icon icon fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";


   var element2 = document.createElement("textarea");
   element2.className="form-control ket_rkb";
   element2.name = "ket_rkb[]";
   element2.rows = "2";
   element2.cols = "70";
   cell2.appendChild(element2);

   var element3 = document.createElement("input");
   element3.className="form-control bobot_rkb";
   element3.type = "text";
   element3.style.width = "45px";
   element3.name = "bobot_rkb[]";
   element3.onchange=hitung_bobot;
   cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.className="form-control target_rkb";
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.style.width = "45px";
    element4.name = "target_rkb[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);
```

I think select2 multiple not working with an array like this []

```
    cell5.innerHTML="<select name='nrk_turunan[]' class='nrk_turunan' multiple='multiple' onchange=''>"+
        "<?php
                            $query = "SELECT NRK,NAMA FROM persoeis@SIMPERS WHERE KD_PEL||KD_DIT||KD_SUB IN (select KD_PEL||KD_DIT||KD_SUB
                                        from persoeis@SIMPERS where nrk = $dapatNRK ) AND jenpeg not in ('4','7','9','c','d','r') AND KD_JNS_JABATAN='1'
                                        UNION
SELECT NRK_PEG NRK,NAMA_PEG NAMA FROM TBL_ATASAN_STRUKTURAL_KOSONG WHERE NRK_ATASAN=$dapatNRK AND KD_PEL_ATASAN||KD_DIT_ATASAN||KD_SUB_ATASAN||KD_SEK_ATASAN=$vargabungkode";
<code>
                $sqlquery = oci_parse($conn, $query);
                oci_execute($sqlquery);
                while($row=oci_fetch_array($sqlquery)){
                    if ($dapatNRK == $row['NRK']) continue;
                    echo "<option value='".$row['NRK']."|".$row['NAMA']."'>".$row['NAMA']."</option>";
                }
                ?> </select>";
        $(".nrk_turunan").select2({
            placeholder: "PILIH"
        });
```

.

```
        cell6.innerHTML="<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox_ulangi_rkb[]' id='chkbox_ulangi_rkb[]' onchange='check_ulang_javas(this)'><input type='hidden' name='check_ulang[]' value='0'>";
  }


function delRow_tugas_rkb(row) {
        var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var k=i;
        var bobot = document.getElementsByName("bobot_rkb[]");
        var total_bobot = document.getElementById("total_bobot");

        var iInt = parseInt(k) - 2;
        var intBobot = parseInt(bobot[iInt].value);
        total_bobot.value = parseInt(total_bobot.value) - intBobot;
        document.getElementById('input_rkb').deleteRow(i);

    }
```

insert statement (save.php)

```
foreach($_POST['ket_rkb'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $ket_rkb = htmlspecialchars(escapeSQL(trim($_POST['ket_rkb'][$key])));
            $bobot_rkb = trim($_POST['bobot_rkb'][$key]);
            $target_rkb = trim($_POST['target_rkb'][$key]);
            $check_ulang = $_POST['check_ulang'][$key];

            $rkbInsertDet = "INSERT INTO RKB_PEGAWAI_DETAIL 
                (ID_RKB, RKB, BOBOT,TARGET,FLAG_ULANGI) VALUES ('$get_id_rkb','$ket_rkb','$bobot_rkb','$target_rkb','$check_ulang')
                returning ID into :ID_RKB_DETAIL";

            $obParse = oci_parse($conn, $rkbInsertDet);
            oci_bind_by_name($obParse, ":ID_RKB_DETAIL", $get_id_detail, 32);
            $objExecute = oci_execute($obParse, OCI_DEFAULT);

            //select2 multiple for lopp. whats wrong with my code ??
            foreach ($_POST['nrk_turunan'] as $key => $value2) {
                if ($value2){
                    $KD_NM_NRK = explode("|",$value2);
                    $rkbInsertTurunan = "INSERT INTO RKB_TURUNAN_PEG (ID_RKB_DETAIL, NRK, NAMA_PEG) VALUES ('$get_id_detail','$KD_NM_NRK[0]','$KD_NM_NRK[1]')";
                    $obParse = oci_parse($conn, $rkbInsertTurunan);
                    $objExecute = oci_execute($obParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
                }
            }
        }
    }

if ($objExecute)
    {
oci_commit($conn);
    }else{
oci_rollback($conn);
    }
```

**My question is :**

select2 multiple not working, how to for loop select2 with multiple data

when I save in table look like this
[image]

I want the results like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQizd.png)

whats wrong with my code..
Can someone/anyone please help me?

Sorry For My Bad English

Comment: You can print $_POST variable in save.php file for verifying the data being received in save.ph file or not.

Comment: @SachinRaghav  I have uploaded a new photo, hope you can understand what i mean...

Comment: You can get the selected values using `$_POST['nrk_turunan']`, as its an array so you have to iterate it or convert it into usable format.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes, i get value   using foreach $_POST['nrk_turunan'] but its not working, in each different id its always all row selected are inserted, 
like the example photo above.

you can see my code, what's wrong ? please help me..